# When I run select in sql it is succes and when i run this with exec it is take full time

Tags: c#, sql

I run select in SQL with parameters and this is a success, but when I run the same code in procudure with the same parameters it takes a long time.
what can be the problem???????
here this is succes:

```
declare @nvGuide varchar(50)='6ABDA937-46B2-4932-AA76-27E6417EE3A7',@iSchoolId int =182,@iYearId int =5783
    select iQuantity as iBooks, t1.iStudentUserId as iStudentId, tClass.nvValue as nvClassName , cast( iClassNumber as nvarchar(10) ) as nvClassNumber, 
    TUser.nvFirstName , TUser.nvLastName , 1 as iGuideStatusId,case when isnull (t2.iStudentUserId ,0) = 0 then 0 else 1 end 
    as bNotReturn,
    isnull(TUser.nvMobile, TUser.nvPhone) as nvPhone, 
    t1.sPaymentReceivedWithReturn
    from (select TStudent.iStudentUserId, SUM(iQuantity) as iQuantity, SUM(nPaymentReceivedWithReturn) as sPaymentReceivedWithReturn
          from TStudentOrderItem
          inner join TStudentOrder on TStudentOrder.iStudentOrderId = TStudentOrderItem.iStudentOrderId
          inner join TStudent on TStudent.iStudentUserId = TStudentOrder.iStudentUserId
          inner join TSchoolBookList on TSchoolBookList.iSchoolBookId = TStudentOrderItem.iSchoolBookId
          inner join TBook on TBook.iBookId = TSchoolBookList.iBookId
          where TStudent.iSchoolId = @iSchoolId 

            and TStudentOrderItem.iYearType=@iYearId-1
            and TStudent.iYearType=@iYEarId-1
            and TStudentOrderItem.iSysRowStatus = 1 
            and TStudentOrder.iSysRowStatus = 1 
            and iUsingType in (14, 15, 513) 
            and bReturn<>1
          group by TStudent.iStudentUserId
          having SUM(iQuantity) > 0
      ) t1
inner join TUser on TUser.iUserId = t1.iStudentUserId
inner join TStudent on TStudent.iStudentUserId = t1.iStudentUserId
inner join TSysTableRow tClass on tClass.iSysTableRowId = TStudent.iRisingToClassType and TStudent.iYearType=@iYEarId-1
left join( select distinct TStudent.iStudentUserId
           from  TStudentOrderItem
              inner join TStudentOrder on TStudentOrder.iStudentOrderId = TStudentOrderItem.iStudentOrderId 
              inner join TStudent on TStudent.iStudentUserId = TStudentOrder.iStudentUserId
             inner join TSchoolBookList on TSchoolBookList.iSchoolBookId = TStudentOrderItem.iSchoolBookId
             inner join TBook on TBook.iBookId = TSchoolBookList.iBookId
              where  (isnull(bReturn,0)<>1 and isnull(bIsReturnInProperUse,0)<>1 )--or  bIsReturnInProperUse is null
               and TStudent.iYearType=@iYEarId-1 
               and TStudentOrderItem.iYearType=@iYEarId-1
               AND TStudent.iSchoolId = @iSchoolId 
               and TStudentOrderItem.iSysRowStatus = 1 
              and TStudentOrder.iSysRowStatus = 1 
              and iUsingType in (14, 15, 513)
              and TStudentOrder.iYearType=@iYEarId-1
              and TStudent.iSysRowStatus=1
              
             )t2 on t1.iStudentUserId=t2.iStudentUserId
    order by iRisingToClassType, iClassNumber,nvLastName, nvFirstName
    
    select  TStudent.iStudentUserId,dbo.TBookBase.nvBookName
          from TStudentOrderItem
          inner join TStudentOrder on TStudentOrder.iStudentOrderId = TStudentOrderItem.iStudentOrderId
          inner join TStudent on TStudent.iStudentUserId = TStudentOrder.iStudentUserId
          inner join TSchoolBookList on TSchoolBookList.iSchoolBookId = TStudentOrderItem.iSchoolBookId
          inner join TBook on TBook.iBookId = TSchoolBookList.iBookId
          inner join dbo.TBookBase on  dbo.TBookBase.iBookBaseId =TBook.iBookBaseId
          where TStudent.iSchoolId = @iSchoolId 
            and TStudentOrderItem.iYearType=@iYEarId-1
            and TStudent.iYearType=@iYEarId-1
            and TStudentOrderItem.iSysRowStatus = 1 
            and TStudentOrder.iSysRowStatus = 1 
            and iUsingType in (14, 15, 513) 
            and bReturn<>1
         order by  TStudent.iStudentUserId
```

here this take a long time,
and when I run the procudure from the C # I get the error:
The time allotted for execution has expired. The allotted time elapsed before the operation completed or the server did not respond.

```
exec [dbo].[StudentOrder_GetAllNotReturnBooks_SLCT] @nvGuide='6ABDA937-46B2-4932-AA76-27E6417EE3A7',@iSchoolId=182,@iYearI=5783
```

Comment: Probably this is an example of *parameter sniffing*

Comment: See https://www.sommarskog.se/query-plan-mysteries.html for a full treatment.

Comment: You are using SQLClient which is much slower than running same in SSMS.  The driver in SQLClient is slow.  Using a faster driver like the one used in Entity which make code run faster.

Answer (score 0):

cheak all parametet if they exsits in the table when you run

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).